# SQL query with multiple values in table A whose description is in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A (Territory) that is designed as such

```
<Territory>      <Group_ID1>     <Group_ID2>     <Group_ID3>     <Group_ID4>
Northwest         1               2
North             1
Southwest         4               2
South             4
Other
```

and Table B (Territory Group) that contains Group Descriptions

```
<Group_ID>       <Group_Description>
1                 North
2                 West
4                 South
```

I need to write a query that will select all records in Table A and inplace of showing the ID it reaches out to the Group table (B) and pulls back the description. When I try and join all the ID's from Table A to Table B, it inevitably excludes all rows. I only gave a brief layout of Table A, but there are 50+ rows and some have 0 Group_IDs and some have 4 Group_IDs.

Can I do a select statement with embedded select statements?

```
Select Territory, 
   (Select Group_Description 
    from Territory_Group where Group_ID = Group_ID1) as "Group1_Description, etc etc     
FROM Territory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left outer join to solve your problem. Try the following query

```
select Territory, G1.Group_Description as desc1 , G2.Group_Description as desc2 , G3.Group_Description as desc3 , G4.Group_Description as desc4 
from Territory T 
   left outer join [Territory_Group] G1 on T.Group_ID1 = G1.Group_ID
   left outer join [Territory_Group] G2 on T.Group_ID2 = G2.Group_ID
   left outer join [Territory_Group] G3 on T.Group_ID3 = G3.Group_ID
   left outer join [Territory_Group] G4 on T.Group_ID4 = G4.Group_ID
```

Make necessary extra joins to meet your table design(ie, group0 or any additional groups)

Comment: @realnumber3012 To the given db structure in the question left outer join is the solution.If something is bad about the table structure you must leave this kind of comment on the question.

Comment: @sahalMoidu I believe your answer to be the correct one, i didn't even think to join the Group table multiple times (noob), BUT
Using that query I get a "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error".

Comment: @JoeS What is your database. SQL Server?? How are you executing this query.

Comment: Its COBOL database with a relational overlay called Relativity. Your answer was the correct one, i simply had to reformat the query a little bit

Comment: @sahalMoidu Final Query was `code` SELECT T.TerritoryDescription AS Territory, TG1.GroupDescription AS Group1Desc, TG2.GroupDescription AS Group2Desc ,TG3.GroupDescription AS Group3Desc ,TG4.GroupDescription AS Group4Desc ,TG5.GroupDescription AS Group5Desc
FROM Territory T
LEFT JOIN TerritoryGroup TG1 ON T.TerritoryGroup1_Id = TG1.TerritoryGroup_Id
LEFT JOIN TerritoryGroup TG2 ON T.TerritoryGroup2_Id = TG2.TerritoryGroup_Id
LEFT JOIN TerritoryGroup TG3 ON T.TerritoryGroup3_Id = TG3.TerritoryGroup_Id
LEFT JOIN TerritoryGroup TG4 ON T.TerritoryGroup4_Id = TG4.TerritoryGroup_Id `code`

Comment: You are welcome @JoeS. So the names of columns you posted in the question was slightly different from your original one.

Comment: Slightly @sahalMoidu, but the structure was identical. Your answer got me where i needed to be, and for that i thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need in first table
add field  "territory" in second table
and use query like this

```
SELECT territory, 
MAX(CASE WHEN group_id = 1 THEN Group_Description ELSE '' END) AS desc1, 
MAX(CASE WHEN group_id = 2 THEN Group_Description ELSE '' END) AS desc2, 
MAX(CASE WHEN group_id = 3 THEN Group_Description ELSE '' END) AS desc3, 
MAX(CASE WHEN group_id = 4 THEN Group_Description ELSE '' END) AS desc4
FROM territory_groups
GROUP BY territory
```